# Instr Function Not Finding Substring

Tags: excel, function, vba

I have the following VBA code, which returns "0" for the InStr function:

```
If InStr("ICD-10 & CPT OPC NHSN", "JCMC ICD-10 & CPT OPC NHSN Sep-17 new.xlsx") > 0 Then
   'Do something
End If
```

However, the following code, using the WorksheetFunction.Find function, does locate the substring at position 6:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("ICD-10 & CPT OPC NHSN", "JCMC ICD-10 & CPT OPC NHSN Sep-17 new.xlsx") > 0 Then
    'Do something
End If
```

Why is the WorksheetFunction returning 6 while the InStr function not locating the substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for the `InStr` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function) you will see that the first of the two mandatory parameters is the string to be searched, and the second parameter is the string being looked for.

> **string1**   Required. String expression being searched.
>   **string2**   Required. String expression sought.

So your code needs to be

```
If InStr("JCMC ICD-10 & CPT OPC NHSN Sep-17 new.xlsx", "ICD-10 & CPT OPC NHSN") > 0 Then
   'Do something
End If
```

Comment: I have to look it up every time I use it. I always get it backwards.

Comment: @ScottCraner I get it right 99% of the time (because I use `InStr` more often than a lot of other functions) but on the occasions when I get it backward my first thought is "did I use the correct parameters?", so it doesn't take long to fix.

Comment: I hop back and forth between FIND() on the worksheet, INSTR() in vba, and SUBSTRING() on SqlServer, that I can never keep them straight.

Comment: @ScottCraner No VB.Net in the mix?  That always confused me, back in the days when I worked for a company that actually allowed me to use VB.Net (mumble, grumble, mumble, stupid current company that won't let me use it because I might write code that hacks into the main IT systems :( ), because so many things were identical to VBA but every now and then there was something that was just slightly different. :D

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I used to use that too, and still do just not as often as the other three.  Throw a little Power Shell in the mix, and it is like changing between Portuguese, Spanish, French and Italian with a little Russian just for giggles.